# $interval not repeating task in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a test for my web app so people can click a button and see the application run with some randomly generated values. This is an angular application and this test function lives inside a controller. I'm trying to slow down the function execution because my server / browser can't keep up if I just let it run. I am trying to use $interval to run my function once every 500 ms, but I click the button and it only runs once, then stops.

Here is the test function:

```
$scope.test = function (){
      console.log('in the test function')
      $interval($scope.sendData(), 500, 100)
}
```

and here is $scope.sendData():

```
$scope.sendData = function () {
   console.log('send Data')
   var val1 = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
   var val2 = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
   var val3 = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
   var val4 = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
   var val5 = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
   var val6 = parseInt(Math.random()*1000)
   var str = 'val1=' + val1 + '&val2=' + val2 + '&val3=' + val3 + '&val4=' + val4 + '&val5=' + val5 + '&val6=' + val6
   $http.get('http://localhost:3002/sendFootData?'+str)
}
```

I also tried setInterval and setTimeout, but they did not slow down the function execution and my browser locked up because it couldn't keep up with the server responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass function reference to the `$interval`:

```
$interval($scope.sendData, 500, 100);
```

In case you need to pass additional parameters you can to use additional anonymous function:

```
$interval(function() {
    $scope.sendData(param1, param2);
}, 500, 100);
```

Comment: why no brackets and what if I need to pass params with it in the future? Also, I replaced $scope.sendData with a function literal and that works, so what the difference between that and $scope.sendData()?

Comment: `$scope.sendData()` executes the function immediately: `()` is an invocation operator. However `$interval` expects a function passed as the first argument. In your case you are passing `undefined` since `sendData` doesn't return anything.